# How to add OK button activated when I click Return - HTML

Tags: html

Here is the end of the HTML script:

```html
<div class="buttonbar">
    <button name="Cancel" type="button" onclick="window.KeyboardMaestro.Cancel('Cancel')">Cancel</button> 
    <button name="OK" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="window.KeyboardMaestro.Submit('OK')">OK</button>
</div>
```

How can make OK button activated when I click Return?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Enter Key to Click OK Button</title>
  <script>
    function clickOkOnEnter(event) {
      // Check if the pressed key is Enter (key code 13)
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Trigger the click event of the OK button
        document.getElementById("okButton").click();
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="clickOkOnEnter(event)" />
  <button id="okButton" onclick="alert('OK button clicked!')">OK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to apply your suggestion, but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? - how do I add my code here ? I seem to run out of space..